# MySQL Slave not processing relay logs fast enough

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a Master-Master cluster with 2 Percona 5.5.30 servers. (Lets name them 1 & 2)
The OS is FreeBSD 9.1

I have an issue that server 2 is not processing the relay log fast enough.
I know that for sure, because when i create a new table on server 1, and i immidiatly check the relay-log on server 2, i see the `CREATE` command there, but the table is not being created for another 5-15 minutes or so.

It looks like the thread that is supposed to executing the relay log is halting itself every once in a while, showing `NULL` in its state when executing `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

What can be the reason for that?

**UPDATE**

Processlist: http://pastebin.com/5Pq7f0GF

(I don't know how to paste SQL here...)

Comment: The next time this happens, please post the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`. If the processlist is too long, then run `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user='system user'\G`

Comment: Added to post..

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common.  A slave only has a single IO thread (the slave I/o thread) whereas a master is typically executing multiple queries in parallel.  You should look at your disk I/O usage (like with iostat) to determine if you're bottle necked there or at the CPU (single thread can use only one core).

The 5.6 series of MySQL can use a separate thread for each schema, which may help.

Comment: So there is nothing i can do right now?